# cannot serve static files using caddy + django + gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, static-files, caddy

I'm working on a project that's using caddy as a web server and proxy, django as the backend, and gunicorn as the wsgi.
But everything all works well except I can't serve the static files.

This is my Caddyfile.

```
mydomain.com {
    root * /path/to/staticfile/
    file_server
    encode zstd gzip
    @notstatic {
        not path /path/to/staticfile/*
    }
    reverse_proxy @notstatic app:8000
}
```

Is there anything wrong that I have used?

Answer (score 0):

How about getting rid of the `@notstatic`, i.e.:

```
mydomain.com {
    root * /path/to/staticfile/
    file_server
    encode zstd gzip
    reverse_proxy app:8000
}
```